# random marks in graph using xy-pic

Tags: xy-pic

[image]I used `xy-pic` to draw a graphical model, but strangely enough when I run it, the circle in the downleft corner is always marked with some random marks. It seems to mark the middle of the circle. Does anyone know how to solve this? Would be of great help!

Thanks a lot!

An example of used code is the following:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centerline{     \xymatrix@C=6em@R=2.4em{ 
                   \xy*{\begin{array}{c}s_W,w_1 \\ U_W\end{array}}*\cir<20pt>{}*\cir<22pt>{}\endxy\ar@{<-}[r]|{all \: a}                          & \xy*{\begin{array}{c}s_B,w_1 \\ U_B\end{array}}*\cir<20pt>{}\endxy\ar@{->}[d]|{all \: a \neq a_1}                \\
       \xy*{\begin{array}{c}s_W,b_1 \\ U_W \end{array}}*\cir<20pt>{}\endxy\ar@{<->}[ur]|{all \: a \neq a_1}\ar@{<->}\ar@{->}[u]|{all \: a \neq a_1}  & \xy*{\begin{array}{c}s_B,b_1 \\ U_B\end{array}}*\cir<20pt>{}\endxy\ar@{<->}[lu]|\hole \ar@{<-}\ar@{<-}[l]|{all \: a }  
        }}
\caption{Situation after product update with $a_1$'s draw}\label{fig:a1dpuu}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You have extra arrows at

```
....\ar@{<->}\ar@{->}[u]|{all \: a \neq a_1}  & ....
```

and at

```
.... [lu]|\hole \ar@{<-}\ar@{<-}[l]|{all \: a }
```

After removing them we get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centerline{
\xymatrix@C=6em@R=2.4em{
                   \xy*{\begin{array}{c}s_W,w_1 \\ U_W\end{array}}*\cir<20pt>{}*\cir<22pt>{}\endxy\ar@{<-}[r]|{all \: a}                          & \xy*{\begin{array}{c}s_B,w_1 \\ U_B\end{array}}*\cir<20pt>{}\endxy\ar@{->}[d]|{all \: a \neq a_1}                \\
       \xy*{\begin{array}{c}s_W,b_1 \\ U_W \end{array}}*\cir<20pt>{}\endxy\ar@{<->}[ur]|{all \: a \neq a_1}\ar@{->}[u]|{all \: a \neq a_1}  & \xy*{\begin{array}{c}s_B,b_1 \\ U_B\end{array}}*\cir<20pt>{}\endxy\ar@{<->}[lu]|\hole \ar@{<-}[l]|{all \: a }
        }}
\caption{Situation after product update with $a_1$'s draw}\label{fig:a1dpuu}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try the more modern package [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd) which gives you more flexibility but easier syntax:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzcd}[%
        ,cells={nodes={draw, circle, inner sep=-3.5pt}}
        ,column sep=1.5cm
        ,row sep=1.5cm
        ,every arrow/.append style={shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt}
        ]
    \tikz{\node[draw, circle]{$\begin{array}{c}s_W,w_1 \\ U_W\end{array}$}} \arrow[<->]{dr} & \begin{array}{c}s_B,w_1 \\ U_B\end{array} \arrow{l}[description]{\text{all }a} \arrow{d}[description]{\text{all }a\ne a_1} \arrow[<->]{dl}[description]{\text{all }a\ne a_1}\\
    \begin{array}{c}s_W,b_1 \\ U_W \end{array} \arrow{u}[description, yshift=2pt]{\text{all }a\ne a_1}  \arrow{r}[description]{\text{all }a} & \begin{array}{c}s_B,b_1 \\ U_B\end{array}
    \end{tikzcd}
\caption{Situation after product update with $a_1$'s draw}\label{fig:a1dpuu}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]